# What is wrong with this code to generate new date rows in my Pandas dataframe based on start and end dates?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following table of data with start and end dates relating to specific entities:

Data:

```
ObjectID,WatchListID,StartDate,EndDate
101,1,2017-01-01,2017-06-01
102,2,2017-04-01,2020-01-01
103,3,2017-01-01,2017-04-01
```

I want to turn this into a multi-index dataframe with a single new 'Date' column (multi-indexes set as ObjectID and Date) and rows for every date between StartDate and EndDate in the initial dataframe for each ObjectID, as well as a new 'Active' column of 1s for every date

I have written the following code to itterate through the initial dataframe (although would welcome suggestions if there is a better solution than to itterate which I generally try and avoid) and generate my new dates based on the start and end dates but I am not getting the desired result; what am I doing wrong?

Current Code:

```
import pandas as pd

Watchlist = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\WatchList.csv", index_col="ObjectID")

del Watchlist['WatchListID']
Watchlist.insert(0, "Date", " ")
Watchlist['Active'] = ""

for index, row in Watchlist.iterrows():
    row['Date'] = pd.date_range(start=row['StartDate'], end=row['EndDate'])
    row['Active'] = 1

print(Watchlist)
```

Current Result:

```
ObjectID,Date,StartDate,EndDate,Active
101,"DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-01', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-03', '2017-01-04',
               '2017-01-05', '2017-01-06', '2017-01-07', '2017-01-08',
               '2017-01-09', '2017-01-10',
               ...
               '2017-05-23', '2017-05-24', '2017-05-25', '2017-05-26',
               '2017-05-27', '2017-05-28', '2017-05-29', '2017-05-30',
               '2017-05-31', '2017-06-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=152, freq='D')",2017-01-01,2017-06-01,1
102,"DatetimeIndex(['2017-04-01', '2017-04-02', '2017-04-03', '2017-04-04',
               '2017-04-05', '2017-04-06', '2017-04-07', '2017-04-08',
               '2017-04-09', '2017-04-10',
               ...
               '2019-12-23', '2019-12-24', '2019-12-25', '2019-12-26',
               '2019-12-27', '2019-12-28', '2019-12-29', '2019-12-30',
               '2019-12-31', '2020-01-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=1006, freq='D')",2017-04-01,2020-01-01,1
103,"DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-01', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-03', '2017-01-04',
               '2017-01-05', '2017-01-06', '2017-01-07', '2017-01-08',
               '2017-01-09', '2017-01-10', '2017-01-11', '2017-01-12',
               '2017-01-13', '2017-01-14', '2017-01-15', '2017-01-16',
               '2017-01-17', '2017-01-18', '2017-01-19', '2017-01-20',
               '2017-01-21', '2017-01-22', '2017-01-23', '2017-01-24',
               '2017-01-25', '2017-01-26', '2017-01-27', '2017-01-28',
               '2017-01-29', '2017-01-30', '2017-01-31', '2017-02-01',
               '2017-02-02', '2017-02-03', '2017-02-04', '2017-02-05',
               '2017-02-06', '2017-02-07', '2017-02-08', '2017-02-09',
               '2017-02-10', '2017-02-11', '2017-02-12', '2017-02-13',
               '2017-02-14', '2017-02-15', '2017-02-16', '2017-02-17',
               '2017-02-18', '2017-02-19', '2017-02-20', '2017-02-21',
               '2017-02-22', '2017-02-23', '2017-02-24', '2017-02-25',
               '2017-02-26', '2017-02-27', '2017-02-28', '2017-03-01',
               '2017-03-02', '2017-03-03', '2017-03-04', '2017-03-05',
               '2017-03-06', '2017-03-07', '2017-03-08', '2017-03-09',
               '2017-03-10', '2017-03-11', '2017-03-12', '2017-03-13',
               '2017-03-14', '2017-03-15', '2017-03-16', '2017-03-17',
               '2017-03-18', '2017-03-19', '2017-03-20', '2017-03-21',
               '2017-03-22', '2017-03-23', '2017-03-24', '2017-03-25',
               '2017-03-26', '2017-03-27', '2017-03-28', '2017-03-29',
               '2017-03-30', '2017-03-31', '2017-04-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')",2017-01-01,2017-04-01,1
```

Head of Desired Result (where Object ID and Date are multi-indices and Active is the column):

```
ObjectID,Date,Active
101,01-Jan-17,1
101,02-Jan-17,1
101,03-Jan-17,1
101,04-Jan-17,1
101,05-Jan-17,1
101,06-Jan-17,1
101,07-Jan-17,1
101,08-Jan-17,1
101,09-Jan-17,1
101,10-Jan-17,1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manipulations where you explode from a date range to a single row per date tend to be slow. Here's a straight-forward method that uses a slow apply to create the `daterange` and then uses `explode` to turn that into a row for every date.

```
import pandas a pd
#df[['StartDate', 'EndDate']] = df[['StartDate', 'EndDate']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

df['Date'] = df.apply(lambda r: pd.date_range(r.StartDate, r.EndDate, freq='D'), axis=1)

df = (df.assign(Active=1).drop(columns=['StartDate', 'EndDate']).explode('Date')
        .set_index(['ObjectID', 'WatchListID', 'Date']))

print(df)
#                                 Active
#ObjectID WatchListID Date              
#101      1           2017-01-01       1
#                     2017-01-02       1
#                     2017-01-03       1
#                     2017-01-04       1
#                     2017-01-05       1
#...                                 ...
#103      3           2017-03-28       1
#                     2017-03-29       1
#                     2017-03-30       1
#                     2017-03-31       1
#                     2017-04-01       1 
#[1249 rows x 1 columns]
```

---

The above is straight-forward, but slow because of the `apply`. Instead, if performance is key we can use some more clever methods to achieve the same. Since you're keeping all the information static and just incrementing the day we can achieve this using `Series.repeat` and then adding 1 day to each row within the group. The addition can be achieved with an optimized `gropuby` + `cumsum` and add with `pd.to_timedelta`.

```
# Repeat all static information
df = (df.set_index([*df]).assign(Active=1)['Active']
        .repeat((df['EndDate'] - df['StartDate']).dt.days + 1)
        .reset_index().drop(columns='EndDate'))

# Increment the Day
df['Date'] = df['StartDate'] + pd.to_timedelta((df.groupby(['ObjectID', 'WatchListID', 'StartDate'])
                                               ['Active'].cumsum()-1), unit='D')
# Clean up columns, create MultiIndex
df = df.drop(columns='StartDate').set_index(['ObjectID', 'WatchListID', 'Date'])
```

---

Timings:

```
import perfplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def repeat_addtimedelta(df):
    df = (df.set_index([*df]).assign(Active=1)['Active']
            .repeat((df['EndDate'] - df['StartDate']).dt.days + 1)
            .reset_index().drop(columns='EndDate'))

    df['Date'] = df['StartDate'] + pd.to_timedelta((df.groupby(['ObjectID', 'WatchListID', 'StartDate'])
                                                   ['Active'].cumsum()-1), unit='D')
    
    df = df.drop(columns='StartDate').set_index(['ObjectID', 'WatchListID', 'Date'])
    
    return df


def apply_explode(df):
    df['Date'] = df.apply(lambda r: pd.date_range(r.StartDate, r.EndDate, freq='D'), axis=1)

    df = (df.assign(Active=1).drop(columns=['StartDate', 'EndDate']).explode('Date')
            .set_index(['ObjectID', 'WatchListID', 'Date']))

    return df


perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: pd.DataFrame({'ObjectID': range(n), 'WatchListID': 100+np.arange(n), 
                                  'StartDate': pd.date_range('2010-01-01', freq='D', periods=n),
                                  'EndDate': pd.date_range('2010-06-01', freq='4D', periods=n)}),
    kernels=[
        lambda df: repeat_addtimedelta(df),
        lambda df: apply_explode(df),
    ],
    labels=['Repeat+Add', 'Apply+Explode'],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(1, 12)],
    equality_check=lambda x,y: x.compare(y).empty,  
    xlabel='len(df)'
)
```

[image]